# Reference request: alternative references on tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, tensor-products, tensors

Before this question gets down-voted into oblivion let me explain what I mean.

The standard reference book I use for (perhaps basic) Abstract Algebra is Dummit and Foote, but its exposition on the tensor product of modules is barely readable (At least in my opinion)

I learned more about the construction of the tensor product of modules from this Wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules

Is there any (better) self-contained reference for tensor product of modules (apart from Dummit and Foote), that I can look at?

Comment: Ch. 2 of Atiyah-Macdonald, *Commutative Algebra*,  *Modules* is well done, in my opinion. A thorough treatment, of course, is Bourbaki, *Algebra*, Ch. II, *Linear Algebra*, §3 *Tensor Products*, but I wouldn't recommend it to beginners (it's a *treatise*, and Ch. II is more than 200 pp.)

Comment: Conrad has a nice exposition article on tensor products:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf

Comment: As Jack said, K. Conrad has two nice blurbs about tensorial products. The only caveat is that he works with modules over commutative rings.

Answer (score 1):

For me Rotman's *An Introduction to Algebraic Topology*'s section of Tensor products of Abelian groups was what I needed. It is concise, contains motivation behind the product and has a few results. Then to extend from Abelian groups to general $R$-modules you add the relation $ar \otimes b = a \otimes rb$ (for $r\in R$ and $a,b \in A,B$ respective right and left $R$-modules)

Comment: I have Rotman's book with me right now, I've only gone through the stuff on Category Theory so I didn't get to that section yet, but I'll definitely give it a look at!